# Hibernate @JoinFormula but getting more than one result back ( a collection ), how?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jpa

The below code snippet does not work:

```
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinFormula("""
        (SELECT DISTINCT ON (product11.id, text26.language, textsourced28.source) text26.id
        FROM product AS product11
                 JOIN producttexttitle AS producttexttitle27    ON product11.id            = producttexttitle27.product
                 JOIN text             AS text26                ON producttexttitle27.text = text26.id
                 JOIN textsourced      AS textsourced28         ON text26.id               = textsourced28.text
        WHERE product11.id=id
        ORDER BY product11.id, text26.language, textsourced28.source, textsourced28.time DESC)
    """)
    private List<Text> titles;
```

**However this does,**

```
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinFormula("""
        (SELECT DISTINCT ON (product11.id, text26.language, textsourced28.source) text26.id
        FROM product AS product11
                 JOIN producttexttitle AS producttexttitle27    ON product11.id            = producttexttitle27.product
                 JOIN text             AS text26                ON producttexttitle27.text = text26.id
                 JOIN textsourced      AS textsourced28         ON text26.id               = textsourced28.text
        WHERE product11.id=id
        ORDER BY product11.id, text26.language, textsourced28.source, textsourced28.time DESC
        LIMIT 1) 
    """)
    private Text titles;
```

The only problem is that the latter one only returns one instance, where I am looking for several.

Can figure it out.

`@CollectionTable` or `@ElementCollection` usage perhaps?

I need to supply a custom sql.

Comment: It is difficult to suggest something without understanding the relationship between your entities. Could you please explain your problem on simplified example.

Comment: @SternK I mean, i am mostly interested in getting a List of Text rather than just one text. That is the core of the question, but I will entertain you. Usually, the join formula is intended for getting the last entity of something, in this case Text associated with Id. For me, I would like to get the last Text per language. That means using that query, I would normally get last texts for each language. Thats it really. A product has a title normally, which might change. So we need to get the last one. Only we do that per language.